# How to show current played video in all pages likes udemy in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, video-player

I am creating an online_learning app and I can play video but I want to show current played video when I quit from playing video.

Comment: Check out state management solutions like Provider. Then when you start playing the video, you can update let’s say a string called currentVideo. Then you could use that string wherever else you need it (to display a banner for example).

Comment: Can you give sample tutorial for me?

Comment: https://youtu.be/8II1VPb-neQ